# How to connect multiple sql instances installed in same azure vm via internet

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql

I have an Azure VM which has installed two sql server instances (Sql server 2012 and sql server 2016). First I installed the SQL server 2012 and could able to connect via internet using Sql Server Management Studio. I referred this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect/). 
 
 Then I installed the Sql Server 2016 on the same VM with the instance name "MSSQLServer2016" but when I try to connect this instance on SSMS it does not connect. I used "vm_public_ip/mssqlserver216" as the server name. Both instances have configured for SQL authentication mode and trying to log in using sa accounts 
 
It is possible to do this ? If so, what I have missed here?

Comment: @the port should be different. You should open two ports on Azure NSG.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports multiple instances of the Database Engine, Analysis Services, and Reporting Services on the same computer. You can also upgrade earlier versions of SQL Server, or install SQL Server on a computer where earlier SQL Server versions are already installed. More information please refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx)

However, you had better not install two SQL instances on one VM. The reasons have to do with the SQL Server memory manager and CPU scheduler architecture, it really works best if it has the whole box to itself and nothing else runs on the box. 'Partitioning' of resources (max server memory, affinity mask) solves some problems and introduces more.